# Can't deploy to GAE - the application doesn't exist

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

Using Eclipse, I am experiencing an error when trying to deploy a rather basic web app with JAX-RS and JAXB.  It runs okay locally, but when trying it on the remote servers I get the message shown below...

'Deploying  to Google' has encountered a problem / This application does not exist

[image]

Below shows my appengine-web.xml

[image]

The XML file illustrates that I am using the same name in the xml as what's specified in the project properties...

[image]

The output window show...

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: '/var/folders/n8/6by626014jbfc0dwmxnb0ly00000gn/T/appcfg2754901216637807129.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Initiating update.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=hillingarincident&version=0&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'hillingarincident').


Debugging information may be found in /private/var/folders/n8/6by626014jbfc0dwmxnb0ly00000gn/T/appengine-deploy447984481661870877.log
```

The referenced debug logs show...

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=hillingarincident&version=0&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u'hillingarincident').

        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:644)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:449)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:124)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:371)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Any answers will be appreciated.  At one point my browser was not logged in to the target google account, so I swapped to the correct one a little later, Google does render the application name as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this was simple in the end!  Eclipse performs an auto-login to the Google account, unfortunately I created the Eclipse project whilst being logged in to one Google account and then tried to specify the application name afterwards.

You'll see in the bottom-right (or bottom-left in some versions) a Google icon with the name of the user that you are logged in as.  If that's not the account where your application is defined, then simply logout of that account, then login as the correct Google account.

Now there's no error :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is super old but I had this issue all day and finally I found a solution. Maybe it will help someone out in the future.

After you create a project in Google Cloud Platform, you must go to google cloud shell in your project and run the command

```
gcloud beta app create
```

After you run this command, you will get prompted to choose a region. Then go back to eclipse and try deploying it. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Zafer, in my case it was an authentication problem which I marked as the accepted answer (because it solved my problem) and evidently since others have up-voted the answer implying that it worked for them.  I've up-voted yours, because this sounds like another good answer for some people, but I can't verify it because I do not do GAE any more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are not just 1 way can cause this problem. For me, I have this problem when I create the project using Maven. But I don't have the same issue if I directly create the project from the Google plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another issue, when you register with Google App Engine, you receive email indicating your activation. If you have not received the email yet, this problem could occur too.
Another issue could be to use the gmail account for the Google App Engine to avoid any such errors.